# The difference between `poetry add` and `poetry install`

Tags: python, dependencies, python-poetry

I've thought that `poetry add package` would simply add the package to `pyproject.toml` but it seems it doesn't just add but also installs it in a virtual environment.

But what does `poetry install` do? When I run it after I added the deps with `add`, I am getting the following message:

```
Installing dependencies from lock file

No dependencies to install or update
```

Note that I started a project from scratch with `mkdir new_dir; cd new_dir; poetry init`.

Comment: I think the [docs](https://python-poetry.org/docs/cli/#install) are quite clear on what the commands do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`poetry add library_name` installs the library and adds it to the `pyproject.toml` file. Note - both installs the library and adds it to the file.

`poetry install` is used when you've directly edited the `pyproject.toml` file and added the dependency names manually. In that case, they aren't installed yet, so, `poetry install` takes care of that.

Answer (score 1):

the `add` command adds packages to your pyproject.toml and installs them.

The `install` command reads the pyproject.toml file from the current project, resolves the dependencies, and installs them.

Refer the [docs](https://python-poetry.org/docs/cli/#add)